# Is there a non-arbitrary criterion to choose which points to use for interpolation?

Tags: regression, dataset, experiment-design, curve-fitting, interpolation

Look at the image. I have to interpolate this experimental points with a voigt function to find the position of the center of the peak, I have to choose how many points and which points to use in the interpolation. I have chosen the green points arbitrarily. Is there a non-arbitrary criterion to choose which points to use for interpolation?
[image]

Comment: Visually the plot appears to have smaller peaks added to the main central peak, one on each side. This might be a good clue, as to characterize the main peak only, that "side peak" data is not helpful. As a first cut at the problem, I would only use data above the level of what appears to be the two side peaks.